# GPG advantages / disadvantages, is it useful or secure?

Tags: public-key-infrastructure, key-management, key-exchange

I thinking about GPG, is very widely used, but is secure? Why and where we using GPG?

I found an [article](http://ask.slashdot.org/story/02/02/07/2147247/pgp-vs-gnupg-in-big-business) from 2002, but is very old.

Comment: Useful for what? Secure for what?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[GnuPG](http://www.gnupg.org/) implements the [OpenPGP format](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc4880). Despite a few quirks due to its old age, it is reasonably secure (no serious weakness has been found yet in its usage of cryptography).

OpenPGP was initially meant for emails. It works well for that and plugins are available for various emailing software. The sore point of secure emails (encryption and/or signatures) is about making sure that you know the *correct* public key for any correspondent. OpenPGP relies on the [Web of Trust](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Web_of_trust) concept, which is neat but, in practice, does not work well (it requires a thoroughly redundant graph of cross-user certifications, that is unlikely to ever exist). If you can make sure that you have the right key (e.g. by exchanging the public key fingerprints in person or over a phone call), then OpenPGP works well (I do that with customers).

Other usages include validation of software packages. For instance, this is integrated in the format for [Debian packages](http://wiki.debian.org/SecureApt) and thus used in some major Linux versions (including Ubuntu).

Comment: thanks for your comment :), the last paragraph is sounds interesting, so can I verify an application originality what I downloaded from internet?

Comment: The idea of signed packaged is that, by verifying the signature, you make sure that the package is exactly, down to the last bit, the same file as what the _signer_ had. It won't guarantee that the application is secure or correct or nice; but it does protect against malicious alterations on data in transit or in mirror sites.

Comment: "No serious weakness has been found yet in its usage of cryptography" is not correct. It has had its problems, some very serious. It is nonetheless true that most people have never encountered or been affected by these bugs, and the software has a good reputation.

Comment: Interesting, I can't found a good article about this. Thank you.

Comment: Was exchanging public keys using ECC not there the time of this post?